# Condensing many line statements that differ only in sequential incremented object name

Tags: python

I have a number of statements in my code that follow the same format below. I'm looking for a method or built-in function which I can use to condense these examples further, more than the existing list comprehensions. Examples are given below:

```
sample_1_combined = [i for i in zip(sample_1_genes, mean_values)]
sample_2_combined = [i for i in zip(sample_2_genes, mean_values)]
sample_3_combined = [i for i in zip(sample_3_genes, mean_values)]
sample_4_combined = [i for i in zip(sample_4_genes, mean_values)]
sample_5_combined = [i for i in zip(sample_5_genes, mean_values)]
sample_6_combined = [i for i in zip(sample_6_genes, mean_values)]

sample_1_final = sorted(sample_1_combined, key=lambda expvalues: expvalues[0])
sample_2_final = sorted(sample_2_combined, key=lambda expvalues: expvalues[0])
sample_3_final = sorted(sample_3_combined, key=lambda expvalues: expvalues[0])
sample_4_final = sorted(sample_4_combined, key=lambda expvalues: expvalues[0])
sample_5_final = sorted(sample_5_combined, key=lambda expvalues: expvalues[0])
sample_6_final = sorted(sample_6_combined, key=lambda expvalues: expvalues[0])
```

Elsewhere in the application, there are more blocks which utilize each separate list, such as:

```
sample_1_graph = [j for i, j in sample_1_final]
sample_2_graph = [j for i, j in sample_2_final]
sample_3_graph = [j for i, j in sample_3_final]
sample_4_graph = [j for i, j in sample_4_final]
sample_5_graph = [j for i, j in sample_5_final]
sample_6_graph = [j for i, j in sample_6_final]
```

And the final block in this format:

```
plt.hist(sample_1_graph, bins=21, histtype='stepfilled', normed=True, color='b', label='278')
plt.hist(sample_2_graph, bins=21, histtype='stepfilled', normed=True, color='g', alpha=0.5, label='470')
plt.hist(sample_3_graph, bins=21, histtype='stepfilled', normed=True, color='r', alpha=0.5, label='543')
plt.hist(sample_4_graph, bins=21, histtype='stepfilled', normed=True, color='c', alpha=0.5, label='5934')
plt.hist(sample_5_graph, bins=21, histtype='stepfilled', normed=True, color='m', alpha=0.5, label='6102')
plt.hist(sample_6_graph, bins=21, histtype='stepfilled', normed=True, color='y', alpha=0.5, label='17163')
```

The above code after modifying is now:

```
# Compute row means.
mean_values = []
for i, (a, b, c, d, e, f) in enumerate(zip(sample_1_values, sample_2_values, sample_3_values, sample_4_values, sample_5_values, sample_6_values)):
    mean_values.append((a + b + c + d + e + f)/6)

# Provide proper gene names for mean values and replace original data values by corresponding means.
sample_genes_list = [i for i in sample_1_genes, sample_2_genes, sample_3_genes, sample_4_genes, sample_5_genes, sample_6_genes]

sample_final_list = [sorted(zip(sg, mean_values)) for sg in sample_genes_list]

# Plot an overlayed histogram of normalized data.
sample_graph_list = [[j for i, j in sample_final] for sample_final in sample_final_list]

colors = 'bgrcmy'
alphas = ['0.5', '0.5', '0.5', '0.5', '0.5', '0.5']
labels = ['278', '470', '543', '5934', '6102', '17163']

for graph, color, alpha, label in zip(sample_graph_list, colors, alphas, labels):
    plt.hist(graph, bins=21, histtype='stepfilled',
             normed=True, color=color, alpha=float(alpha), label=label)
```

Comment: By "condese" do you mean that you want to have 6 instead of 12 lines? Or do you want to move the common code into a function?

Comment: Yes, decrease total code. I experimented with functions, but need to call the variables outside local scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If possible, make a nested list `sample_genes_list = [sample_1_genes, ...]`

And then

```
sample_final_list = [sorted(zip(sg, mean_values) for sg in sample_genes_list]
```

This should be equivalent to your current code, because:

1. The list comprehensions do nothing if you have Python 2 or are equivalent to `list()` for Python 3. `sorted` takes any iterable, so it doesn't matter.
2. Tuples are sorted by the 0-th element first naturally.

Update in response to the question edit:

```
sample_graph_list = [[j for i, j in sample_final]
        for sample_final in sample_final_list]
```

**Edit 2:** and finally:

```
colors = 'bgrcmy'
labels = ['278', '470', '543', '5934', '6102', '17163']
for graph, color, label in zip(sample_graph_list, colors, labels):
    plt.hist(graph, bins=21, histtype='stepfilled',
             normed=True, color=color, label=label)
```

Comment: @user2277435 I'm guessing you could do `sample_graph_list = [[j for i, j in sample_final] for sample_final in sample_final_list]`

Comment: Great suggestion so far. I'm going to replace, see how far I can trickle down the nested expressions. If there are no unseen complications, I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: @user2277435 You can always use explicit loops if the nested comprehensions start to look too heavy. But overall, I don't think there can be any problems with the list approach. Feel free to update the question and comment here so that I get a notification if you have any difficulties.

Comment: Having an issue modifying last block of code to properly parse each dataset for graph inclusion from sample_graph_list. Suggestions?

Comment: @user2277435 You need a list of colors, a list of labels, `zip` and a `for` loop. I'll update the answer with code in a couple of hours, when I'm at the PC again.

Comment: Thank you considerably. This was very instructive in nested list comprehensions. This should scale very well.